# How to use ng-repeat with filter and $index?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to use ng-repeat in Angular, while I only want to output some elements of the array. An Example:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter:($index%3 == 0)"
```

However, this does not work. Please tell me how to do this; only output exact index of elements.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In your code, filter apply on 'items' array, not on each array item, that's why it does not work as you expect.

Instead, you can use ng-show (or ng-if):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="$index % 3 == 0">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/H7d26

EDIT: Use ng-if directive if you do not want to add invisible dom elements:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hello, i think this will not be a good way, angular will output some useless dom into page, if you do nothing with other hidden items. DotDotDot had provided a good idea to do it. thanks anyway.

Comment: You can use ng-if instead of ng-show, it will not add dom elements. See: http://jsfiddle.net/H7d26/2

Comment: thanks! both ways can achieve my work, while i think ng-if can do it faster and easier. i really need to read the document carefully.

Answer (score 16):

Create a custom [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09), for example:

```
filter('modulo', function(){
  return function (arr, div, val) {
      return arr.filter(function(item, index){
          return index % div === (val || 0);
      })
  };
});
```

Then change the `ng-repeat` to:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items | modulo:3">
```

Or filter by `(index % 3 === 1)` like:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items | modulo:3:1">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tc34P/2/

Comment: hello, i know filter can do this, while if i want to output (index%3==0),(index%3==1),(index%3==2)in three different part of webpage,they i have to write three filters, is it right? i think there is a way to transfer a parameter.

Answer (score 9):

What you need to do is find the index of "item" in $scope.items. See below

```
ng-repeat"item in items | filter:(items.indexOf(item)%3 == 0)
```

So a real world example (for others who come across this solution) would be.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filtered = (items | filter:customfilter | orderBy:customsort)">
    <div> This is number {{items.indexOf(item)}} in the items list on the scope.</div>
</div>
```

The above example will get the correct position regardless of the sorting or filtering

Answer (score 2):

All the precedent answers will work, but if you want to use a filter, you can also define it yourself, like in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/58y7u/

```
.filter('myFilter', function(){
    return function(data, parameter){
        var filtered=[];
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                if(i%parameter==0)
                    filtered.push(data[i]);
        }
        return filtered;
    }
});
```

and then call it like this :

```
ng-repeat='item in items | myFilter:3'
```

(I added extra complexity with a parameter, if you want to change it quickly to even numbers for example)

Have fun

++

Answer (score 1):

I suggest filtering with a function:

```
ng-repeat"item in filterItems(items)"
```

And on the Controller:

```
$scope.filterItems= function(items) {
    var result = {};
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
       // if item is something.. add to result
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This will work, but it can be quite expensive with a long list, just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach to solving this creates a new "list" (I don't know the proper term in this context) in the `ng-repeat`. This new list can then be referred to within the scope

```
<ul class="example-animate-container">
  <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in filteredFriends = ((friends | filter:q:strict) | orderBy:'age')" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">
    [{{$index + 1}}] {{filteredFriends[$index].name}} who is {{filteredFriends[$index].age}} years old.
    <span ng-if="$index+1 < filteredFriends.length">[{{$index + 2}}] {{filteredFriends[$index+1].name}} who is {{filteredFriends[$index+1].age}} years old.</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `ng-if` on the `span` wrapping the second half prevents the base text from being shown when the previous element is the last element of the list.