# Get every third value from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array `arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']` and I want to get every third value into a  new `arr2 = ['three', 'six', 'nine']`.

I tried `for` loop but I can't get it to work properly. What's the best way to do this using jQuery or just javascript?

Comment: Look for "modulo operator"

Comment: You should show what you tried so we can help spot where you went wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use ng-repeat with filter and $index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858395/how-to-use-ng-repeat-with-filter-and-index)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) function

```
var arr2 = $.grep(arr, function( n, i ) {
    return i % 3 == 2;
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3tdvt5zr/)

Comment: @Steve: `$.grep` is `filter` in plain JS. If you don't need to support ancient browsers, use `filter`.

Comment: @Steve: Also note that using `.grep` (or `filter`) will touch every element in your array. Since you know you only need every third element, a regular `for` loop that increments by `3` is more efficient (see Josh's answer). Not that it's likely to make much difference with only 9 elements anyway.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a `for` loop if you want!

Consider the following:

```
var arr1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var arr2 = [];

for (var i = 2; i < arr1.length; i += 3) {
    arr2.push(arr1[i]);
}

arr2; // ["three", "six", "nine"]
```

Comment: yeah same as my anwer and i get a -2

Comment: @bto.rdz That's because your answer _does not produce the result requested by the OP_.

Comment: @bto.rdz: It's not the same answer. Even if yours produced the right answer, this would still be more efficient.

Comment: haters of incorrect, poorly thought-out answers, yes we are!

Comment: You beat me to it @JoeT

Comment: @bto.rdz if you put as much time into your answer as you are putting into complaining about fake points, then we wouldn't even be having this discussion.