# AngularJs ng-repeat in group class

Tags: javascript, angularjs-ng-repeat

Colleagues;

i have this:

```
app.controller("pedidosCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.eventos = [{nome: 'Nome do evento 1',descricao:'Descricao 01',preco: 10.00},
    {name: 'Nome do evento 2',description:'Descricao 02',preco: 20.00},
    {name: 'Nome do evento 3',description:'Descricao 03',preco: 60.00},
    {name: 'Nome do evento 4',description:'Descricao 04',preco: 60.00},
    {name: 'Nome do evento 5',description:'Descricao 05',preco: 60.00},
    {name: 'Nome do evento 6',description:'Descricao 06',preco: 60.00}];
});
```

And HTML

```
<body ng-controller="pedidosCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat = "e in eventos">Nome do evento: {{e.nome}} </td>
</body>
```

Ok. Works perfectly.

But if you want a div involving every 3 iterations, resulting in something like:

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        nome do evento 1
        nome do evento 2
        nome do evento 3
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        nome do evento 4
        nome do evento 5
        nome do evento 6
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

Just found solutions for this complex problem and could not apply any of them

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858395/how-to-use-ng-repeat-with-filter-and-index) show how you can set modulos in ng-repeat. So what about this:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="e in eventos" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">
    {{eventos[$index]}}
    {{eventos[$index + 1]}}
    {{eventos[$index + 1]}}
</div>
```