# Conditional wrapper on ul in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a `ng-repeat` with `ul` list inside and i want to create a `ul` every 8 elements but i can't find the way.
I have to use `$index % 8 == 0` to show the `ul` conditionally but i don't know how.
This is my code so far:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="v in values" ng-show="false"/>
  <ul>
    <li ng-class="{'active':  filterContent.isSelectedValue(key, v) }" ng-click="filterContent.addFilter(key, v)">
      <a  class="issue-btn btn-default">{{v}}</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
<div ng-repeat-end ng-show="false"/>
```

The output result would be something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>... content... </li>
   <li>.... content... </li>
   <!-- 8 times -->
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>.... more content ... </li>
   <li>.... more content ... </li>
   <!-- 8 times -->
</ul>
<!-- and so on until repeat ends -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with two nested ngRepeat's. Something like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="v in values" ng-if=":: $index % 8 === 0">
    <li ng-repeat="v in values.slice($index, $index + 8)" ng-class="{active: filterContent.isSelectedValue(key, v)}" ng-click="filterContent.addFilter(key, v)">
        <a  class="issue-btn btn-default">{{v}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is a simple demo:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
  <ul ng-repeat="v in values" ng-if=":: $index % 8 === 0">
    <li ng-repeat="v in values.slice($index, $index + 8)" ng-class="{active: filterContent.isSelectedValue(key, v)}" ng-click="filterContent.addFilter(key, v)">
      <a class="issue-btn btn-default">{{v}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is the `::` on the `ng-if`? (with that `::` it doesn't work for my but if i remove those, then it works)

Comment: This is [one-binding operator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding), it is better for performance. I assume you are using Angular < 1.4.x? Then yes, just remove `::`.

Answer (score 1):

As demonstrated here : [How to use ng-repeat with filter and $index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858395/how-to-use-ng-repeat-with-filter-and-index)

you can do that easily with an ng-if on the li :

```
<div ng-repeat-start="v in values" ng-show="false"/>
  <ul>
    <li ng-class="{'active':  filterContent.isSelectedValue(key, v) }" ng-click="filterContent.addFilter(key, v)" ng-if="$index % 8 == 0">
      <a  class="issue-btn btn-default">{{v}}</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
<div ng-repeat-end ng-show="false"/>
```

Comment: but with this solution, when the `ul` is being shown there will be only one `li` inside

Comment: In your question you want to add ul is it a typo and you want to create li every 8 elements ? (I edited my answers to add the ng-if on the li)